# Save char array to NSPasteBoard

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

I need to save unsigned char array to `NSPasteBoard` and then read it. How I can do it? I tried to save it to `NSString`, but this working only with ASCII codes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [StackOverflow: How to ask a good question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question by clicking the `edit` button to add more information so we can help you. As it stands your question is likely to be closed as *Off Topic*

Comment: You should apply more context, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char myChars[] = "This is a test";
NSData *charsData = [NSData dataWithBytes:myChars length:strlen(myChars)];
[[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] clearContents];
[[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] setData:charsData forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];

NSData *data = [[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] dataForType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
char myChars2[data.length];
[data getBytes:myChars2 length:data.length];
NSLog(@"%s", myChars2);
```

Answer (score -1):

The question is a bit unclear. Do your application use pasteboard to communicate with other apps or just to store data between launches?

**1. Your application needs to store binary data for itself between launches.** 
I suggest you to use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) for that purpose. As it said in docs, it's a database so you may achieve data even in next application launch.

```
static const NSString *kCharsDefaultsKey = @"kCharsDefaultsKey";

- (void)saveChars:(unsigned char *)chars length:(size_t)length
{
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:chars length:length];
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standartDefaults];
  [defaults setValue:data forKey:kCharsDefaultsKey];
  [defaults synchronize];
}

- (void)getChars:(unsigned char *)chars length:(size_t)length
{
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standartDefaults];
  NSData *data = [default valueForKey:kCharsDefaultsKey];
  if(data)
  {
    [data getBytes:chars];
  }
}
```

**2. Your application needs to push data between some apps.**

The pasteboard-mechanism can be a way to establish this kind of communication. But I strongly recommend you to choose another way. You can't be sure there isn't another data inside the pasteboard.

```
- (void)someMethod
{
  NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
  NSArray *contents = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:@[[NSData class]] options: nil];
  // how should you distinguish which object contains your chars and which doesn't?
}
```

I would rather recommend you to use [NSConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSConnection_Class/index.html).
Also please take a look at this great [article](http://nshipster.com/inter-process-communication/).

Comment: What a terrible idea.  `NSUserDefaults` isn't designed to be a general dumping ground for things you want to save or communicate between objects.  It's designed to save user defaults.

Comment: @Droppy I think It's much more appropriate than containing it in pasteboard. Why binary data can't be some kind of 'user defaults'?

Comment: Because the OP wants to use the pasteboard.  From the pasteboard the data can be copied into other apps.  And as I already mentioned, `NSUserDefaults` isn't a general dumping ground.

Comment: @Droppy the question is a bit unclear. Is pasteboard playing role of inter-process communication object or there's the only application which writes/reads binary data if needed. Are you sure pasteboard should be used any of these ways?

Comment: The OP appears to want to use the pasteboard for its original, designed, intent, and no other reason.